# Check if database backup using pg_dump is in progress

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and using `pg_dump` to create DB backup. How could I determine is db backup and restore is in progress. So I can prevent another user in initiating another.

Comment: My first question would be how come you can have different users with rather high privileges doing such a thing at the same time ?

Comment: @KookieMonster: you don't need any special privileges to run `pg_dump` - all you need is select privileges on the tables you want to dump.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're absolutely right. But if his backup solution is done with such regular users, it might be an issue. I guess he is more worried of a superuser issuing a planned backup and a normal user doing a concurrent backup. I am so far not aware of a backup right that could be enabled or disabled for certain users.

Comment: I have admin users with privileges that can initiate the db dump/backup. Os If backup is already in progress want to inform user.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of is to check `pg_stat_activity.application_name` and see if any session with `pg_dump` (or `pg_restore`) is currently active.

---

`application_name` is a value supplied by the client connecting to the database. So in theory this is not something that can be trusted completely - but I am not aware that `pg_dump` allows you to overwrite this. And if you don't use that information for security purposes this should be OK.

Comment: pg_stat_activity does not have session with pg_dump or pg_restore. Do we will have entry in pg_stat_activity once backup is in progress ?

Comment: @Gaurav: yes, every session that connects to the database is visible in `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: pg_stat_activity is not reliable ? to check db in progress, as in cases it return false. Even if db backup is in progress :-(